# CSS - bottom border around a TD gets cut off when browser is resized

Tags: css, border, html-table

I have a web app that uses bootstrap to make it mobile friendly. 
In an attempt to visually group 3 items together, I have created a class the puts a box / border around the table cell where these three items appear. (the three items are link4, 5 and 5)

Here's the class:

```
 td.lights
 {
   border: 2px solid black;
 }
```

And here's the problematic HTML - I've paired it down to the minimum code, just for demo purposes.
What I'm noticing is that when I simulate a mobile device (using Firefox's Responsive design view tool) the bottom of the

```
      <table>
          <tbody>
                  <tr>  

                  <td>link1</td>        
                  <td>link2</td>    
                  <td>link3</td>    
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td class="lights">link4&nbsp;/&nbsp;link5&nbsp;/&nbsp;link6</td>

              </p>
          </tbody>
          </table>
```

Immediately after this table, I have this code to create another table:

```
         <P>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                                etc...
                            </thead>
                            </table>
```

When i resize my browser, the border on the bottom of my  in table 1 gets cut off, depending on how small by browser size gets. The other fields look fine, but then again, they don't have a border around them. To me, it looks like there's a fixed set of space above and below my text ("link4 / link5 / link6") that is not dynamically changing. 
I've tried adding a height "dynamic" height property to my td like so:

```
 td.lights
 {
   border: 2px solid black;
   height: 1em;
 }
```

But that didn't resolve my problem.
Any suggestions?  Please and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you have quite a few errors in your markup:

```
</p>
```

Should be:

```
</tr>
```

Also, should you have a:

```
<P>
```

Before your second table? I would avoid wrapping your tables with P tags as this will add unwanted padding and doesn't make sense from a semantic perspective.

Fix those first and see what happens. Secondly I would recommend - when dealing with tables - to use the following:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
```

You can also do this in CSS with the following:

```
table, tr, td { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; }
```

This should make sure you have no unwanted padding in and around your cells.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions.  I've implemented them all.  As far as the border is concerned, now it's cutting off the left side vs. the bottom.

Comment: I've added cellpadding and that fixes the left side.  But the interesting thing is that now I have the oppposite problem.  When the browser shrinks, the border is ok... but when the browser size grows, the bottom gets cut off.